# rc.local not running second script if first is '/opt/lampp/lampp start'

Tags: linux, lampp

I have on script to stop network manager at boot time. I did entry for that in rc.local. its works fine. but on one server MySQL is installed and rc.local already have one entry for start lampp. (/opt/lampp/lampp start).

### after that I did entry for my script. now **rc.local** is like this :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/opt/lampp/lampp start
sh /etc/startupscript.sh
exit 0
```

---

at boot time first entry execute and logs are in **boot.log** are :

---

Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting AppArmor profiles                                            [ OK ]
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.24-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.24-1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.

### XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.

and exit. second line **sh /etc/startupscript.sh** is not execute.

If I execute **rc.local** manually, both script run successfully.
thanks in advance.

Comment: you meant if "/opt/lampp/lampp start" line is not there then startupscript.sh is executed?

Comment: correct Prabhu, it was exit because of last error.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer.. in the first line of rc.local, there is -e meaning "exit on error" I remove it then all script are run successfully. and not impact each other.